# How to specify dynamic tab in a sumifs formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to get the below `SUMIFS` formula to update the worksheet it looks at depending a month referenced in some other cell, say A1.  I have sales data from each month in a separate worksheet so the below formula is summing the data in worksheet'02.13' if it matches each of the criteria specified.  I'd like to have it reference a specific cell to know which worksheet to reference in the `SUMIFS` formula.

```
=SUMIFS('02.13'!E:E,'02.13'!A:A,Dashboard!L8,'02.13'!D:D,Dashboard!M6)
```

So if A1 has my worksheet name or reference, I need it to function as:

```
=SUMIFS('A1'!E:E,'A1'!A:A,Dashboard!L8,'A1'!D:D,Dashboard!M6)
```

I've looked around in several forums and have found some similar questions but I'm having difficulty deciphering the formulas and applying for my specific need.  I think I need to use an `INDIRECT` formula but can't figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with the `INDIRECT` function.

I assume `A1` would will contain the sheet name (i.e. `02.13`) in your example. You can then change your formula to the ff:

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(A1&"!E:E"),INDIRECT(A1&"!A:A"),Dashboard!L8,INDIRECT(A1&"!D:D"),Dashboard!M6)
```